# Integrating $x^2/{(a-bx)}^2$ yields weird result

Tags: calculus, integration

I needed to find the antiderivative of the real valued function $\frac{x^2}{(a-bx)^2}$ with Mathematica, the result was
$$\frac{a^2}{b^3(a-bx)}+\frac{x}{b^2}+\frac{2a\ln(bx-a)}{b^3}$$
which differentiates perfectly giving the integrand, the problem is with the third term $\ln(bx-a)$, if $bx<a$ "which is always the case for my problem" then this term would yield complex values while I know that it should only yield real values, how can I deal with this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of $\log{kx}$ is $1/x$ for any $k$ (easy enough to check), so you can instead choose
$$ \frac{a^2}{b^3(a-bx)}+\frac{x}{b^2}+\frac{2a\log{(a-bx)}}{b^3} $$
(you can check that this has exactly the same derivative as Mathematica's original answer).

Comment: Many thanks man, it differentiates exactly the same, you made my day.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to express the antiderivative of $\dfrac 1x$ is $\ln |x|$. The answer should read
$$\frac{a^2}{b^3(a-bx)}+\frac{x}{b^2}+\frac{2a\ln|bx-a|}{b^3}, \quad x \not= \frac ab.$$

Comment: Thanks Umberto P. I didn't know that